# Chrome extension to jump to base URL?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, url

a couple of years ago I found an extension for Google Chrome that made it possible to jump to the base URL with one simple click. I can't find it any more. Does anyone know of such an extension?

To describe the desired functionality, take these URLs for example.

The current URL in the browser would be:

- https://superuser.com/questions/ask

And the URL I would want to jump to then is:

- https://superuser.com/

At the moment, when I want to switch, I click the URL bar/field and manually remove the trailing URL path. This feels complicated. :)

The extension that I am looking for - if it still exists - would do this via a simple, single mouse-click on the extension icon (to the right of the URL field).

Any feedback appreciated. Sebastian

Comment: I don't know. If you found it a couple of years ago and used it then what happened to that computer? You might be able to hire a programmer of chrome extensions quite cheaply to do that.. I suggest you make a list of chrome extensions you use and find useful 'cos otherwise you will forget this/that extension

Comment: Hey barlop.

Cool! Thanks for the advice. Yes, I should keep track of what I have used in the past (I tell you, if my head wouldn't be fixed to my upper body, I would have a huge problem ;)).

Kidding aside, can you point me to a platform where I could find and hire a decent programmer. I guess you are right, the functionality that I am looking for should be super-easy to implement.

Comment: You could try fiverr and there are some other websites maybe upwork or freelancer

Comment: Hey barlop, fiverr sounds great. I just contacted one of the freelancers there. I'll post an update when I got news :) Thanks.

Comment: Okay, just for the sake of completeness. The pointer to fiverr was a bullseye. There's now an extension by the name of "Touchdown" which does exactly what I was looking for. Maybe other people can benefit from it as well. Thanks again! Awesome =D

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/touchdown/dkgclagfnpppkcgalbaemjffilmnokpb